# What is the meaning of "otherwise" in this text?

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

The head on the obverse is archaic in type, and very much resembles that of Sapor I. The crown has attached to it, in many cases, that "cheek-piece" which is otherwise confined to the first three monarchs of the line. These coins are the best from an artistic point of view; ...

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The meaning of `otherwise` in this sentence is `in other respects; apart from that`.

So you could say:

The crown has attached to it, in many cases, that "cheek-piece" which is **otherwise(in other respects/apart from that)** confined to the first three monarchs of the line.

Hope this gives you the answer.....

Comment: I don't think it does... _Except for the coin which is being discussed_, the 'cheek-piece' is only pictured on coins of the first three monarchs.